# how can i choose image/picture for my nodes in gexf or networkx

Tags: networking, diagram, networkx, topology

my project's aim is to generate a network diagram, I've made a program that creates objects as swicth and nodes in python then it generates a gexf file and my question is :

Can everybody tell me if he knows a way that allow us to choose a node image by using gexf, networkx or other tools.

Thank you so much

Comment: networkX supports adding images as an attribute for the node e.g. `G =nx.Graph() G.add_edge(0,1, image= my_img)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetworkX supports adding any form of data as attributes for a node such as an image:

```
G=nx.Graph() 
G.add_edge(0,1, image=my_img)
```

Essentially everything is stored as a dictionary underneath.